# Difficulty getting usable response from secured ArcGIS REST API 10.2

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, request

I am trying to script the export of subsets of data from an ArcGIS Server to clients based on shapefiles they provide me. Our data are on a somewhat old rest endpoint (10.2). I have tried a variety of approaches in Python (requests, REST API,  ArcGIS API for Python) and would like to avoid ArcPy.. I'm going to present the cleanest one I've tried here.

There are a number of layers within the feature server that I would like to extract from. Using the manual query form at the endpoint, after logging in with my credentials, I'm able to obtain HTML and JSON responses effectively. For these manual requests, I've been converting client shapefiles to Esri JSON and then pasting the geometry into the form.

When connecting via Python I obtain a token using my credentials as follows:

```
token_url = 'https://server.edu/arcgis/tokens/generateToken/'
data = {'username' : username, 'password':password, 'client':'requestip'}
token_request = requests.post(url = token_url, data = data)
token_text = token_request.text
```

Using the token in a simple query (select one record by id) via `requests.post` works, returning a JSON-ish string.

```
r6 = requests.post('https://server.edu/arcgis/rest/services/myservice/FeatureServer/query?layerDefs={"10":"OBJECTID=8672"}&returnGeometry=true&token='+token_text+'&f=json')
r6.content

b'{"layers":[{"id":10,"objectIdFieldName":"OBJECTID","globalIdFieldName":"","geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","spatialReference":{"wkid":26912,"latestWkid":26912},"fields":[{"name":"OBJECTID","alias":"OBJECTID","type":"esriFieldTypeOID"},{"name":"featureNUM","alias":"featureNUM","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble"},{"name":"govtNUM","alias":"govtNUM","type":"esriFieldTypeString","length":30},{"name":"site_name","alias":"site_name","type":"esriFieldTypeString","length":100},{"name":"recorder","alias":"recorder","type":"esriFieldTypeString","length":255},{"name":"rec_date","alias":"rec_date","type":"esriFieldTypeString","length":50},{"name":"prop_id","alias":"prop_id","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble"},{"name":"gis_source","alias":"gis_source","type":"esriFieldTypeString","length":20}],"features":[{"geometry":{"rings":[[[303288.6568,3792149.1231999993],[303288.65789999999,3792649.1345000006],[303463.65930000041,3792649.1348000001],[303463.65809999965,3792149.1234000009],[303288.6568,3792149.1231999993]]]},"attributes":{"OBJECTID":8672,"featureNUM":61409,"govtNUM":"NO189CA","site_name":"","recorder":"Bobbity, Bob","rec_date":"04/12/1978}04/12/1978","prop_id":null,"gis_source":"OTHER"}}]}]}'
```

However, attempting a spatial query using urllib.parse.urlencode, the extracted "rings" text from the Esri JSON, and `requests.post` returns an HTML-formatted response (despite f=json) with no apparent data, even when I just try to get a count of intersecting features.

```
poly_str = '{ "rings" : [ [ [ 395281.25846107356, 3705278.9142870069 ], [ 395259.08817898418, 3705278.8045034055 ], [ 393796.00222100894, 3705291.8724438325 ], [ 393773.83483585611, 3705292.0986727839 ], [ 393751.66825861123, 3705292.4165414446 ]]]}' 
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'f':'json','token': token_text, 'geometryType':'esriGeometryPolygon','geometry': poly_str, 'spatialRel':'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields':'','returnCountOnly':'true'})
req = requests.post(server_url, params)
response = req.content
response
```

Here's what the response content looks like:

```
b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<title>ArcGIS Server REST API Login</title>\r\n<link href="/arcgis/rest/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<table width="100%" class="userTable">\r\n<tr>\r\n<td class="titlecell">\r\nArcGIS REST Services Directory\r\n</td>\r\n<td align="right">\r\n<a href="https://server.edu/arcgis/rest/login">Login</a> | <a href="https://server.edu/arcgis/tokens/">Get Token</a>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<table width="100%" class="navTable">\r\n<tr valign="top">\r\n<td class="breadcrumbs">\r\n<a href="/arcgis/rest/services">Home</a>\r\n</td>\r\n<td align="right">\r\n<a href="https://server.edu/arcgis/sdk/rest/02ss/02ss00000057000000.htm" target="_blank">Help</a> | <a href="https://server.edu/arcgis/rest/services?f=help" target="_blank">API Reference</a>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<h2>ArcGIS Server REST API Login</h2>\r\n<div class="rbody">\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\nfunction onLoad() {\r\n    if (top.location != self.location) {\r\n      top.location = self.location;\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n</script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/arcgis/rest/static/js/BigInt.js"></script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/arcgis/rest/static/js/Barrett.js"></script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/arcgis/rest/static/js/RSA.js"></script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/arcgis/rest/static/js/admin.js"></script>\r\n<form action=https://server.edu/arcgis/rest/login method="post" onsubmit="return encryptFormData(\'10001\',\'\',\'eaa67450bc6c3dc6bc3445e558540c40a263b44c35c33634ddacd79f7217cd926d5e8fb99d3ec3becf626ecdd13124f1755ce1ed82d764795e06ee43168e56f3\');">\r\n<table class="formTable">\r\n<tr valign="top">\r\n<td>User Name:</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<input type="token" name="username" value="" />\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr valign="top">\r\n<td>Password:</td>\r\n<td>\r\n<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td colspan="2" align="left">\r\n<input type="submit" value="Login" />\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://server.edu/arcgis/rest/services/myfeatures/FeatureServer/10/query"/>\r\n</form>\r\n</div>\r\n<br/><br/>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

I don't know if the onsubmit="returnencryptFormData" means I'm getting an encrypted response or what.

Will it be possible for me to pass spatial queries to this REST endpoint and get usable output?
I have looked a lot of previous questions and have been unable to back out what my problem is.

Comment: First off, if you're not running 10.2.2 with the scores of applicable patches, you need to do that first. There are tons of zip-n-ship samples in various languages. I had no difficulty implementing this in Java, but I wonder about the Python available back then being stable enough.

Comment: If your response is pumping out what is basically a webpage of the services directory, this means something has gone wrong with the request. The best way to debug this is to use something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to try and spy on the request to make sure it's sending as expected.